# Clicking noise coming from rear

Tags: mountain-bike

When I first set out on my bike for the first 10 minutes there is a very audible clicking sound coming from the bike.

After 10 minutes have passed the sound disappears. It's coming from either the Bottom Bracket area or Rear Wheel area but I have looked at it and cannot figure out what is causing it.

Any ideas? Bike model is a Pinnacle Ramin 3

Comment: If the click is coming from the rear hub and is occurring, with a regular rhythm, just while you're coasting, that's normal.  Some bikes are noisier than others in this regard.

Comment: The hub is supposed to be mostly silent the noise coming is like a bad mechanical clicking noise that you can tell should not be happening.

Comment: Some hubs are silent, some aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinnacle is Evans Cycles' house brand. Evans offers a [free "6-week" check up](https://www.evanscycles.com/help/servicing/free-check-up) with all new bikes. Ensure they note the spoke tension problem on the worksheet when you book the bike in.

When wheels are built, the spokes can hold a smooth curve through a crossing point, especially with thicker plain-gauge (unbutted) spokes, rather than forming a kink at the crossing point. With normal "J-bend" spokes, the bend at the elbow may keep its original 90 degree angle and prevent the head from settling properly in the hub drillings. Over time, this bend may tighten or loosen (depending whether it passes through the hub flange outwards or inwards) until the head is properly flat against the face of the hub flange. Both of these stresses may settle over time causing spoke tension to be lost. Experienced wheelbuilders will attempt to relieve most of this stress before finally ensuring the wheel remains true and has the correct tension.

Another cause of tension-loss with lighter butted spokes is wind-up, whereby as the tension is increased during the build, friction between the spoke threads and nipple threads can prevent the nipple from screwing further onto the spoke, causing the body of the spoke to twist instead. As the wheel is used, the twist-tension of wind up can release itself by unscrewing the spoke from the nipple or by spinning the nipple within the rim. Wind-up can be limited by using proper lubrication at the nipple threads and where the nipple sits in the rim, and by using brass washers between the nipple and rim (especially with a rim that doesn't have eyelets). When choosing lighter spokes, a bladed spoke (such as the Sapim CX-ray) allows the wheelbuilder to see wind-up and prevent it by holding the flat section of the spoke.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check the rear quick release is on *tight*.
A lose rear quick release can cause clicking issues / noises from the bottom bracket.

2) Check the tightness of the chainring bolts.
Make sure they are tight. Some alloy chainring bolts will cause clicks as the chainset is placed under strain on hard efforts.

3) Your bottom bracket is worn or loose?
Check the fitting is flush and tight.
Check if the bearings still feel smooth when turning the chainset.
A press-fit BB should be dry-fit.
A threaded BB should be greased.

Comment: Ok, I have tried all of these and everything seems fine. It does happen when I dont pedal if that helps at all. Ill list below what I have checked

Comment: I have checked: BB, Pedals, Cranks, Wheels, Spokes, Hubs, Quick Releases, Seat Post and Clamp, I also cleaned the hell out of both derailuers and that did not fix it either

Comment: Does it happen ONLY when you don't pedal? It goes away when you pedal? It's definitely something with your freehub. It could be as Daniel said in his comment above that it's just a louder mechanism than you're used to. Or it could be something is wrong in the mechanism. Without hearing/seeing it, it's hard to say.

Comment: It happens both when I pedal and when I don't, however I have to add pressure to the bike. I was looking at it and found it might be one of the spokes are a little lose. Squishing to of the together lightly produces the same sound. The wheels not even a month old.

Comment: It disapears after about 10 minutes of riding the bike and comes back the next day I go out on it

Comment: Sounds a lot like spoke that is poorly seated, slightly loose or has some twist in it. Google for "spoke stress relieving" and try how it works.

Comment: Yeah, spokes can be noisy when they are not properly tensioned (and sometimes even when they are).

Answer (score 0):

If it is full suspension mtb bike, it is possible that the cracks are caused by worn joints of the full suspension (bearings).

Comment: It's a hard tail